# Loop through dictionary to subtract values

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that keeps track of each material part and its inventory amount. The material part is assigned as the key and its inventory amount as the value.

```
dictionary = {'A': 100, 'B': 200, 'C': 300,'D': 400,'E': 500,'F': 600,'G': 700,'H': 800,'I': 900,'J': 1000,'K': 1100,'L': 1200}
```

With these material parts, I create products that are made up of varying amounts of the different material part that I stored in the form of a string `product = '1A 2B 3C'`

With each product I make, I updated the dictionary of material parts

```
for x in product.split(): 
        value, key = x[:-1], x[-1]
        dictionary[key] -= int(value)
```

This results in `dictionary = {'A': 99, 'B': 198, 'C': 297.....`

This next part is where I'm stuck. When I want to make 3 of the same product, I'm going to have to loop through the string to update the dictionary three times.

I wish to make it so that if there isn't sufficient inventory of any material part, it prints the products that were already made and the outstanding amount which is something like this:

```
dictionary = {'A': 2, 'B': 6, 'C': 9}
product = '1A 2B 3C'
quantity = 3

# Program sees that there is sufficient quantity to make 2 quantities of product with one outstanding. 
#Updates the dictionary with the 2 quantities and then print:
```

Comment: you are likely to get more help if you could also add a sample input and the expected output.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia just added it in, hope it makes things easier to understandd

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia that is just test code, i'm trying to figure out how to incorporate the dictionary part to it

Comment: I thought so as well, so my earlier comment was asking for the input dict, your sample string and the expected output for the dict object and anything extra that you expect. currently, what you have mentioned in the question is not the full desired output rather it is the actual output which is not much useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dictionary = {'A': 100, 'B': 200, 'C': 300,'D': 400,'E': 500,'F': 600,'G': 700,'H': 800,'I': 900,'J': 1000,'K': 1100,'L': 1200}

product = '1A 2B 3C'

quantity = 101

made = 0

while quantity:
        possible = True
        for x in product.split():
                value, key = x[:-1], x[-1]
                dictionary[key] -= int(value)
                if dictionary[key]<0:possible = False
        if not possible:
                print("Insufficient quantity")
                print(f"{made} product made at the current inventory level")
                print(F"{quantity} outstanding")
                for x in product.split():
                        value, key = x[:-1], x[-1]
                        dictionary[key] += int(value)
                break


        made +=1
        quantity-=1

if quantity == 0:
        print(f"{made} product successfully made")
```

What this code does is, for the part when system detects that this iteration is gone beyond scope of inventory, it fixes the numbers, stops the iteration and prints the messages.

I tried to keep the code as close to your logic provided in question as possible.

For test case 1:
quantity = 7
Output:

```
7 product successfully made
```

For test case 2:
quantity = 101
Output:

```
Insufficient quantity
100 product made at the current inventory level
1 outstanding
```